# How can I use sed to output the current and previous directory while including a tilde if $HOME is one directory further?

Tags: regex, sed, command-prompt, zsh, fish

Currently my `zsh` prompt utilizes `$'%2~ %%'` to output the current and previous directory before just displaying `%` as my input prompt. For example, if I'm in `/Users/david/Documents/Code/project`, my prompt will display:

`Code/project %`

However, if I back up into the `Code` directory, a tilde is shown:

`~Documents/Code %`

I'm trying to reproduce this in the `fish` shell by replacing the regex provided in their `prompt_pwd` function and gets passed to `sed`. By default, that function looks like:

```
function prompt_pwd --description 'Print the current working directory, shortend to fit the prompt'
  echo $PWD | sed -e "s|^$HOME|~|" -e "s|^/private||" -e 's-\([^/]\)[^/]*/-\1/-g'
end
```

Currently, this outputs the full name of the current directory, but truncates all other directories to one character (and replaces `$HOME` with a tilde). I'm trying to figure out what regular expression I can provide that function to duplicate what I had going on in zsh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest:

```
echo $PWD | sed -e "s|^$HOME/|~|" -e 's-.*/\([^/]*/[^/]*\)-\1/-'
```

Comment: This did pretty much just what I wanted! I removed the trailing slash, but everything else worked great. Thank you so much!

Comment: This was very close, thanks. I had to modify like this to get a proper `~/` prefix (a little hacky): `sed -e "s|^$HOME/||" -e 's-.*/\([^/]*/[^/]*\)-\1/-' | sed "s/^/~\//"`